# How to insert tableview row animate from bottom of tableview height to top in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

[image]

I need to insert tableview cell and it should slide from bottom of tableview height to top.I am calling following code on button tap.But it is not coming from bottom.

```
 [array_messages addObject:message];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[array_messages count]-1 inSection:0];
[self.tableViewMessage insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use the following `UITableView` `dataSource` method to specify the animation

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let frame = cell.frame
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.height, frame.width, frame.height)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        cell.frame = frame
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

In objc

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *) cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGRect frame = cell.frame
    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.height, frame.width, frame.height)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve  animations:^{
      [cell setFrame:frame];
      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   }];
}
```

Modify the animation to suit your need

Comment: I need this in objective c.

Comment: i am getting  this error "No member named with width and height in struct CGRect"

Comment: Thank you very much @Mathews. You have saved my days .Finally i got success.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3, Xcode 8.1

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let frame = cell.frame
    cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tableView.frame.height, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
        cell.frame = frame
    }, completion: nil)

}
```